# Boot Camp not able to find Mac image

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, bootcamp, restore, mojave

I am using a 2015 15" MacBook Pro with 512 GB storage. There are a couple of issues that happened very quickly, so I will give you the comlete timeline:

1. I logged into macOS.
2. I noticed that Caps Lock is on, and doesn't respond; the same thing with the letter that is between o and q.
3. I panicked. I logged into Windows (using Boot Camp).
4. The same thing repeats.
5. Now when I try to get back to macOS (used <kbd>Option</kbd>, used Boot Camp in windows, even tried recovery mode to repair disk,) I boot into Windows, and there is no Mac image in Boot Camp.

I have upgraded to macOS Mojave. I have allotted 150 GB to Windows and 350 to macOS. When I see the storage in windows it is showing only 465 GB. I don't know what to make of it.

I don't use Time Machine.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work again, are you able to boot into the recovery partition? (Try rebooting while holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> keys). If not, try booting into Target Disk Mode using Boot Camp, and then try booting into the recovery partition.

Once on it, try using `diskutil` to see if the drive is functional.

Basically, (when on the recovery partition) launch Terminal and type `diskutil list`. It will give you a list of current disks. Please add that list, or even a picture of your screen with that list, so that I can identify which `disk#s#` you need to boot onto/repair/reinstall macOS to.

But, if you're lucky, booting into Target Disk Mode and then into the recovery partition will fix this.

As for why Caps Lock and "that key between o and q" (I don't know what that is) weren't responding, that may be a keyboard issue, I don't really have any way of knowing without checking it out.